# Layout with two sliding side panels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to figure out how to create a simple mobile first layout with two sliding panels. Basically, if the width of the viewing area is less than 700px I would like the layout to look like this:

[image]

This will mostly be for mobile screens and allow the user to click the hamburger menu in the top left to have the left menu slide in to the left, or click the ellipsis in the top right to have the right menu slide in from the left. Seems simple but I want both menus to be fixed so when the main content is scrolled through the menus don't get put up at the top.

Also, when the viewing area is over 700px I want the two menus to show automatically like this:

[image]

I was wondering if someone could help me with this real quick. I can't seem to nail it down. I appreciate it.

Comment: Please post what you have so far.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! We're happy to help, but we prefer you to include all the relevant code-snippets into your question, rather than pointing to images of what you'd like offsite. This is because links can go stale, but we want Stack Overflow questions to be Forever (in case somebody else has the same problem you do).  Can you please edit your question, and add all the relevant code you've written? Also in your question, add the things you've tried and why they weren't successful for you. Then we can begin to help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To achieve the responsive requirement, you could use [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to set specific CSS styles to the screen size you want.
2. To achieve the fix top menu bar, you could refer to [position:fixed](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)